# Read an arbitrary number of bytes from type implementing Read

Tags: io, rust

I have something that is `Read`; currently it's a `File`. I want to read a number of bytes from it that is only known at runtime (length prefix in a binary data structure).

So I tried this:

```
let mut vec = Vec::with_capacity(length);
let count = file.read(vec.as_mut_slice()).unwrap();
```

but `count` is zero because `vec.as_mut_slice().len()` is zero as well.

`[0u8;length]` of course doesn't work because the size must be known at compile time.

I wanted to do

```
let mut vec = Vec::with_capacity(length);
let count = file.take(length).read_to_end(vec).unwrap();
```

but `take`'s receiver parameter is a `T` and I only have `&mut T` (and I'm not really sure why it's needed anyway).

I guess I can replace `File` with `BufReader` and dance around with `fill_buf` and `consume` which sounds complicated enough but I still wonder: Have I overlooked something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. Fill-this-vector version

Your first solution is close to work. You identified the problem but did not try to solve it! The problem is that whatever the capacity of the vector, it is still empty (`vec.len() == 0`). Instead, you could actually fill it with empty elements, such as:

```
let mut vec = vec![0u8; length];
```

The following full code works:

```
#![feature(convert)] // needed for `as_mut_slice()` as of 2015-07-19

use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;

fn main() {
    let mut file = File::open("/usr/share/dict/words").unwrap();
    let length: usize = 100;
    let mut vec = vec![0u8; length];
    let count = file.read(vec.as_mut_slice()).unwrap();
    println!("read {} bytes.", count);
    println!("vec = {:?}", vec);
}
```

Of course, you still have to check whether `count == length`, and read more data into the buffer if that's not the case.

---

#### 2. Iterator version

Your second solution is better because you won't have to check how many bytes have been read, and you won't have to re-read in case `count != length`. You need to use the `bytes()` function on the `Read` trait (implemented by `File`). This transform the file into a stream (i.e an iterator). Because errors can still happen, you don't get an `Iterator<Item=u8>` but an `Iterator<Item=Result<u8, R::Err>>`. Hence you need to deal with failures explicitly within the iterator. We're going to use `unwrap()` here for simplicity:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;

fn main() {
    let file = File::open("/usr/share/dict/words").unwrap();
    let length: usize = 100;
    let vec: Vec<u8> = file
        .bytes()
        .take(length)
        .map(|r: Result<u8, _>| r.unwrap()) // or deal explicitly with failure!
        .collect();
    println!("vec = {:?}", vec);
}
```

Comment: I have thought about something like that but isn't that rather inefficient? It looks like allocation of the `Vec` changes from O(1)ish to O(n).

Comment: Sure, but you're going O(n) anyway when filling the vector, so it's a matter of `2n` vs. `n`, which is not *that* bad. I would be more worried about the check `count == length` which is avoided in the 2nd version (see edit).

Comment: I guess the question boiled down to "how do I create a `Vec` with a particular length`. When I think about it, higher-level languages that shield the developer from this probably do this behind the scenes, too. Otherwise I'm aware of error handling and checking the number of bytes actually read. I just left it out for brevity. Thanks. :)

Comment: Your solution with `bytes()` actually has the same problem as my `take()`: It consumes the `file` but I only have a borrowed mutable reference to the file so this doesn't work. - Ok, I have no idea what's going on. It does work with a reference to the file but not if I have a reference to a struct that contains the file.

Comment: @musiKk *"It looks like allocation of the Vec"* looks can be deceiving, and Rust / LLVM do an amazing job of optimizing iterators. You need to look at assembly to actually know how much is allocated. I'll point to [`Iterator::size_hint`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.size_hint) as a concrete example of how it can be more efficient as well.

Comment: Please use `vec![0u8; length]` to build the vector, it's shorter, performs better, and should be the idiom.

Answer (score 6):

Like the Iterator adaptors, the IO adaptors take `self` by value to be as efficient as possible. Also like the Iterator adaptors, a mutable reference to a `Read` is also a `Read`.

To solve your problem, you just need [`Read::by_ref`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.by_ref):

```
use std::io::Read;
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let mut file = File::open("/etc/hosts").unwrap();
    let length = 5;

    let mut vec = Vec::with_capacity(length);
    file.by_ref().take(length as u64).read_to_end(&mut vec).unwrap();

    let mut the_rest = Vec::new();
    file.read_to_end(&mut the_rest).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: I found out I don't even have to call `by_ref()`. Rust seems to do it automatically on a `&File`, it also doesn't seem to be necessary to be mutable. This confuses me greatly! Is `by_ref()` some sort of magic method?

Comment: @musiKk No, it is not magic, it's actually extremely simple, [its implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/cb87ea80a6f3411c889f9a48b65724b32659c171/src/libstd/io/mod.rs#L352-L353) is one line and the body is one keyword. The fact that a reference works seems... incorrect to me. I might have to ask my own question!

Comment: Don't sweat it, [I'm done with one of my own](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31503429/why-can-i-call-file-take-on-a-reference). ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a bit of `unsafe` to create a vector of uninitialized memory. It is perfectly safe to do with primitive types:

```
let mut v: Vec<u8> = Vec::with_capacity(length);
unsafe { v.set_len(length); }
let count = file.read(vec.as_mut_slice()).unwrap();
```

This way, `vec.len()` will be set to its capacity, and all bytes in it will be uninitialized (likely zeros, but possibly some garbage). This way you can avoid zeroing the memory, which is pretty safe for primitive types.

Note that `read()` method on `Read` is not guaranteed to fill the whole slice. It is possible for it to return with number of bytes less than the slice length. There are several RFCs on adding methods to fill this gap, for example, [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/980) one.

Comment: This is very interesting. For now I went with `file.take(length).read_to_end(vec)`. I had a problem with a move out of a borrowed struct that I now managed to fix. That's why I dismissed this solution in my question.