# Why can I call File.take() on a reference?

Tags: file, rust, immutability, borrow-checker

When I look at [`File`'s docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/fs/struct.File.html), I see that the `take` method takes a `self`, not a `&self`. But I'm still able to call the method on a borrowed reference:

```
fn foo(file: &File) {
    let _ = file.take(1); // why does this work?
    println!("can still use the file: {:?}", file);
}
```

I thought a `self` passes ownership but I'm even able to use `file` after calling `take` so ownership clearly stays inside `foo`.

If I do it myself on a custom struct with a method, it doesn't work:

```
struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    fn foo(self: Foo) { }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = &Foo;
    foo.foo(); // error: cannot move out of borrowed content
}
```

which is fully expected.

Likewise according to the docs, `File` does not implement any special traits as far as I can tell. What did get my attention is that `Read` has a `by_ref()` method but I don't call it yet everything still works.

What's going on here? (using rustc 1.3.0-dev)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `take` method comes from the `Read` trait. That trait is implemented on `File`, so there is a method `File::take(self, u64) -> Take<Self>`, but the trait is also implemented on `&File` (the impl is even listed on the very page you link to). For that impl, the `Self` type is `&File`, so *its* `take` method takes a reference.

Comment: This also answers my other question: "What is the point of those two `impl`s?" I had no idea it worked that way. Thanks!