# Why is it possible to implement Read on an immutable reference to File?

Tags: rust, immutability

If you check out the [docs for `Read`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html), most of the methods accept a `&mut self`. This makes sense, as reading from something usually updates an internal offset so the next read returns different data. However, this compiles:

```
use std::io::Read;
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let file = File::open("/etc/hosts").unwrap();
    let vec = &mut Vec::new();
    (&file).read_to_end(vec).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", vec);
}
```

The file isn't mutable, but the data is certainly being read in. This seems incorrect to me. [It was pointed out that there is an `impl<'a> Read for &'a File`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31503429/155423), but the fact that an immutable instance is seemingly being mutated still seems odd.

Comment: Does the answer to [Why can I call File.take() on a reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31503429/395760) resolve this or are you asking *why* `Read` is implemented on `&File`?

Comment: @delnan The question here is: why is `&file` enough? One should expect `&mut file` be required.

Comment: @delnan (I didn't ask the question, but) I don't think that answers this question. There must be something else going on. `read_to_end` should work on either `&mut File` or `&mut &File`, but `(&file)` is neither of those.

Comment: @fjh: I believe `a.read_to_end(vec)` will call `Read::read_to_end(&mut a, vec)`, i.e. the method already sees `&mut &file`.

Comment: @delnan the two questions sprang from the same source, but to have something useful to add, I'm curious both "why" and "how" `Read` can be implemented on an immutable reference and I've tweaked the question accordingly.

Comment: there is no such thing as immutable in Rust. &mut just means, that you have exclusive access to a reference.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As @kennytm pointed out, `a.read_to_end(vec)` is equivalent to `Read::read_to_end(&mut a, vec)`, so `(&file).read_to_end(vec)` expands to `Read::read_to_end(&mut &file, vec)`. In the latter expression, `&file` is a new temporary value of type `&File`. There is no problem with taking mutable references to an expression (e.g. `&mut 42`). This is exactly what happens here. The fact that the expression is a reference to an immutable value doesn't matter because we cannot actually mutate the value through a `&mut &T`.

Regarding the question why we don't need the `File` to be mutable: `File` is basically just a newtyped file descriptor, i.e. an index into an open-file table that is managed by the OS. `read` and friends will not change this descriptor at all, which is why the `File` does not need to be mutated. There is of course mutation going on, but that is done by the operating system on its own data structures and not in your user-land rust code.

Comment: +1 for "mutation [...]  is done by the operating system on its own data structures and not in your user-land rust code." I believed having an (immut) `&File` meant that nothing could happen to your file; this answer show it's not the case, which is IMO counter-intuitive. Maybe this deserves a clarification in the docs.

Comment: @mdup perhaps it's just best for us to think of `File` as having a [cell](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/index.html) of some kind.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Yeah, it's like a file has its own built-in mutex. The OS takes care of its synchronization.