# When should I use `&mut self` vs. `&self` in Rust bindings for a C library?

Tags: rust, ffi

I'm unsure when to use `&mut self` vs. just `&self` in the Rust bindings for the libzmq C API.

A bit of background: libzmq provides socket "objects", which have an API similar to the BSD socket API, and are represented by an opaque pointer in C. This pointer is really just a handle, similar to POSIX file descriptors, and the C API is designed so that it is *not* possible to obtain any references to memory behind that pointer.

Under these circumstances, is it safe and good API design to expose socket methods with an immutable `self`? As a concrete example, consider [`zmq_send()`](http://api.zeromq.org/4-2:zmq-send):

```
int zmq_send (void *socket, void *buf, size_t len, int flags);
```

I think it can (and should) be exposed using immutable self, i.e.:

```
pub fn send(&self, data: &[u8], flags: i32) -> Result<()> { ... }
```

However, comparable Rust standard library methods use `&mut self`, e.g. [`std::io::Write::write()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#tymethod.write), as implemented by `std::net::TcpStream`. On the other hand, `std::net::UdpStream::write()` takes just `&self`. My guess is that `&mut self` is used just because it is an implementation of the `Write` trait, which in turn (I guess) uses `&mut self` to not constrain implementations of the trait.

I hope someone can back up or refute my speculations here -- I could not find anything specific about that topic in the Book or the Nomicon.

Comment: Related: [Why is it possible to implement Read on an immutable reference to File?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31503488/155423). In that case, the OS handles multiple uses of the underlying file descriptor, so there's no reason to enforce that in Rust.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case whether the object is mutated is secondary; the main question is "is it safe for two references to be used at the same time?".  Would it be ok for two threads to call `zmq_send` (or other methods) on the same object at the same time, or (if the API allows that) via nested callbacks, etc?

If not, use `&mut self` and let Rust enforce the safety guarantees you need.

If it is safe, then maybe `&self` is appropriate, if `zmq` guarantees it's ok; this would be like `Mutex::lock` taking `&self`.

Comment: I should have added that the socket options in question are not thread-safe, but sharing across threads should be forbidden by the type system if the binding not implementing the `Sync` thread, right? And the libzmq C API does not employ callbacks at all, AFAIK.