# Why does a File need to be mutable to call Read::read_to_string?

Tags: file, rust, immutability

Here's a line from the [2nd edition Rust tutorial](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch12-02-reading-a-file.html#reading-a-file):

```
let mut f = File::open(filename).expect("file not found");
```

I'm of the assumption that the file descriptor is a wrapper around a number that basically doesn't change and is read-only.

The compiler complains that the file cannot be borrowed mutably, and I'm assuming it's because the method `read_to_string` takes the instance as the `self` argument as mutable, but the question is **"why"**?  What is ever going to change about the file descriptor?  Is it keeping track of the cursor location or something?

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow immutable local variable `fdesc` as mutable
  --> main.rs:13:5
   |
11 |     let fdesc = File::open(fname).expect("file not found");
   |         ----- consider changing this to `mut fdesc`
12 |     let mut fdata = String::new();
13 |     fdesc.read_to_string(&mut fdata)
   |     ^^^^^ cannot borrow mutably
```

The whole source:

```
fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let query = &args[1];
    let fname = &args[2];
    println!("Searching for '{}' in file '{}'...", query, fname);

    let fdesc = File::open(fname).expect("file not found"); //not mut
    let mut fdata = String::new();
    fdesc.read_to_string(&mut fdata)
        .expect("something went wrong reading the file");

    println!("Found: \n{}", fdata);
}
```

Comment: Not a Rust expert myself, but I think this is because the File is conceptually mutable, not the number representing it. The in-kernel file represented by the file handle number *is* mutable. Reading or writing it changes its contents and moves the kernel's current position in the file.

Comment: @ZanLynx: Your intuition is correct, and it goes beyond. When using the decorator pattern, as `BufReader` does, the Rust object itself is mutated along the way (the buffer inside).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I'm assuming it's because the method `read_to_string` takes the instance as the `self` argument as mutable

Yes, that's correct:

```
fn read_to_string(&mut self, buf: &mut String) -> Result<usize>
```

The trait method `Read::read_to_string` takes the receiver as a mutable reference because in general, that's what is needed to implement "reading" from something. You are going to change a buffer or an offset or *something*.

Yes, an actual `File` *may* simply contain an underlying file descriptor (e.g. on Linux or macOS) or a handle (e.g. Windows). In these cases, the operating system deals with synchronizing the access across threads. That's not even guaranteed though — it depends on the platform. Something like Redox might actually have a mutable reference in its implementation of `File`.

If the `Read` trait didn't accept a `&mut self`, then types like [`BufReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html) would have to use things like internal mutability, reducing the usefulness of Rust's references.

See also:

- [Why is it possible to implement Read on an immutable reference to File?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31503488/155423)

Comment: I'm confused why in one instance you _can_ `read_to_end` with an immutable `File` (the linked "See also") but you _cannot_ `read_to_string` with an immutable `File`? What am I missing? Why can't `read_to_string` just implement `read_to_end` under the hood?

Comment: @AustinHeller I don't follow — you [_can_ call `read_to_string` on an immutable reference to a `File`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b7993c74c493b72fce1d73d043fad973). Note that an immutable **reference** to a `File` is not the same type as an immutable `File`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I didn't notice that the linked "See also" was using an immutable File reference. I'm still confused though, in one scenario we can use a mutable File instance and in the other we're permitted to use an immutable File reference to an immutable File? I'm very new to Rust, btw, hence what may seem like basic questions.  
Main question: Why would Rust be okay with an immutable reference to an immutable File but *not* okay with an immutable File?

Comment: @AustinHeller in the working case, you create a temporary immutable reference to a `File` then implicitly take a mutable reference to the temporary, producing an `&mut &File`.