# Exposing implementation details in Rust traits

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and, coming from Java world, I wanted to play with Rust trait as I would do with Java interfaces. 
I imagined the following need :

- I must be able to save User (firstname, lastname) somewhere (in a db, a file)
- I can fetch all of them

I started to define the trait that I wanted to have :

```rust
trait UserDb {
    fn get_all(&self) -> Result<Vec<User>, io::Error>;

    fn save(&mut self, user: &User) -> Result<(), io::Error>;
}
```

You can see that when I declare `get_all` function, I don't mention the need to have a mutable borrow on `self` (i.e `&mut self`).

Then I decided to implement this trait with File capabilities (please find the full code at the end).

What surprised me is that, when I read the content of the file, I have to declare `self` as mutable. (here's a reason why : [Why does a File need to be mutable to call Read::read_to_string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47660946/why-does-a-file-need-to-be-mutable-to-call-readread-to-string))

It annoys me because if I do that, I must declare in the trait `self` as mutable, even if I'm reading data. I feel like there is a leak of implementation detail in the trait.

I think my approach is not valid or not idiomatic in Rust. How would you achieve this ?

Here is the full code :

```rust
///THIS CODE DOESNT COMPILE
///THE COMPILER TELLS TO MAKE self AS MUTABLE
use std::fs::File;
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::io;
use std::path::Path;
use std::io::Read;
use std::io::Write;

struct User {
    pub firstname: String,
    pub lastname: String,
}

trait UserDb {
    fn get_all(&self) -> Result<Vec<User>, io::Error>;

    fn save(&mut self, user: &User) -> Result<(), io::Error>;
}

struct FsUserDb {
    pub file: File,
}

impl FsUserDb {
    fn new(filename: &str) -> Result<FsUserDb, io::Error> {
        if Path::new(filename).exists() {
            let file = OpenOptions::new()
                .append(true)
                .write(true)
                .open(filename)?;

            Ok(FsUserDb { file })
        } else {
            Ok(FsUserDb {
                file: File::create(filename)?,
            })
        }
    }
}

impl UserDb for FsUserDb {
    fn get_all(&self) -> Result<Vec<User>, io::Error> {
        let mut contents = String::new();

        self.file.read_to_string(&mut contents)?;

        let users = contents
            .lines()
            .map(|line| line.split(";").collect::<Vec<&str>>())
            .map(|split_line| User {
                firstname: split_line[0].to_string(),
                lastname: split_line[1].to_string(),
            })
            .collect();

        Ok(users)
    }

    fn save(&mut self, user: &User) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
        let user_string =
            format!("{},{}", user.firstname, user.lastname);

        match self.file.write(user_string.as_bytes()) {
            Ok(_) => Ok(()),
            Err(e) => Err(e)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let db = FsUserDb::new("/tmp/user-db");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read` required mutable borrow, there is not much you can do about that.

To solve you problem, there are three options I can think of:

- Modify your signature on the trait to `&mut self` as the compiler recommends to. This is the clearest solution, I'm not sure why you don't like it.
- Use internal mutability like `RefCell` and get the mutable `File` where you need it. With this solution you don't even need to declare `save` as mutable, but adds some runtime cost. I do recommend reading about `RefCell` since that can introduce other kind of errors later on.
- Store the filename, not the `File` handler itself and open/close it when appropriate. With this, you can also use immutable `save`.

Comment: While `RefCell` has a small runtime cost, that cost is going to be negligible compared to reading a file.

Comment: It's not like I really dislike to put `&mut self` in the signature, I just found it weird to say there is a mutation involved when reading data. I think I'll go for the first solution you mention, to follow the compiler hints. Thank you also for giving other options :).