# Why does changing from a TcpStream to a trait cause "cannot borrow immutable borrowed content as mutable"?

Tags: rust

I would like to create a variation of a SOCKS5 proxy using asynchronous IO. I've done this before in Haskell so I thought would be a good learning challenge.  I am starting with the very [well-documented SOCKS5 example code](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio-socks5/blob/a6952adde41289267215c9cdd0487df025214952/src/main.rs).

In the example, the `Transfer` struct requires the reader and writer to be of type `TcpStream`.  In my code these need to be polymorphic, so I started by defining:

```
pub trait Pollable {
    fn poll_read(&self) -> Async<()>;
    fn poll_write(&self) -> Async<()>;
}

impl Pollable for TcpStream {
    fn poll_read(&self) -> Async<()> {
        tokio_core::net::TcpStream::poll_read(&self)
    }
    fn poll_write(&self) -> Async<()> {
        tokio_core::net::TcpStream::poll_write(&self)
    }
}

pub trait AsyncStream: tokio_io::AsyncRead + tokio_io::AsyncWrite + Pollable {}

impl<T> AsyncStream for T
where
    T: tokio_io::AsyncRead + tokio_io::AsyncWrite + Pollable,
{}
```

When I switch the type of `reader` at line 510 from `Rc<TcpStream>` to `Rc<AsyncStream>`, the compiler fails with this error on line 598:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow immutable borrowed content as mutable
   --> src/transfer.rs:125:33
    |
125 |                 let n = try_nb!((&*self.reader).read(&mut buffer));
    |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

Ignore the file and line number in the error message; I'm in the middle of moving the code around to multiple files but it is otherwise identical to the example.

Following advice I found elsewhere on Stack Overflow, I checked the types.  Before the change, the type of `&*self.reader` is `&tokio_core::net::TcpStream`; after the change, the type becomes `&transfer::AsyncStream + 'static`.  I don't know why the `'static` lifetime comes in when I change from a concrete type to a trait...

Why does this happen?  How can I fix it?

Comment: A guess: Maybe `TcpStream` had a method called `read` that took `&self`, but `AsyncStream` (or one of its supertraits) has a method called `read` that takes `&mut self`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`tokio_core::net::TcpStream`](https://docs.rs/tokio-core/0.1.12/tokio_core/net/struct.TcpStream.html) implements [`Read`](https://docs.rs/tokio-core/0.1.12/tokio_core/net/struct.TcpStream.html#impl-Read-1) and [`AsyncRead` for an immutable reference](https://docs.rs/tokio-core/0.1.12/tokio_core/net/struct.TcpStream.html#impl-AsyncRead-1). Your trait does not.

`&*self.reader` converts the `Rc<T>` to a `&T`, which is used as the target of the `read` method.

To fix it, you need to either implement the appropriate trait for an immutable reference to your trait or use some kind of interior mutability.

See also:

- [Why is it possible to implement Read on an immutable reference to File?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31503488/155423)

Comment: Thanks!  This does appear to be my problem.  However I fear I just don't understand enough in this area yet... what would the trait for an immutable reference look like?

Comment: @TomKludy I'm not sure I understand your question. I [linked to an implementation of a trait for a reference](https://docs.rs/tokio-core/0.1.12/tokio_core/net/struct.TcpStream.html#impl-Read-1), so it seems unlikely that you are asking about the syntax needed for such an implementation. Could you clarify your question a bit?

Comment: I tried following the pattern you linked and might be closer..

But now I get error: `cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements`

Thank you for your patient help!

Going to chase this one for a while...