# write! macro does not compile in a separate method when taking reference

Tags: rust, rust-macros

This is my code:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    let f = File::create("").unwrap();

    // Compiles
    write!(&f, "hi").unwrap();

    write_hi(&f);
}

fn write_hi(f: &File) {
    // Doesn't compile (cannot borrow `f` as mutable, as it is not declared as mutable)
    write!(f, "hi").unwrap();
}
```

When I have this line without the file being a parameter value, it compiles:

```
write!(&f, "hi").unwrap();
```

However, when the `f` is a parameter value, I get a compile error. It works when I make some mutability changes in the declaration of the `f` variable and method parameter, but isn't that odd?

Why doesn't the `write!` macro work on a non-mutable reference when it is used as a parameter value, like it does compile when the referencing variable is declared in the same method?

Answer (score 5):

The [`write!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.write.html) macro internally uses [`write_fmt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#method.write_fmt) which takes a `&mut self`. Your `write!(&f, ...)` is actually the odd one since the object being written to should be mutable, however you have an immutable `File`.

How does this work then? `Write` has an additional [implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#impl-Write-10) for `&File`s. So you can write to a mutable reference to an immutable file. I'm not positive, but I believe this was added as a deliberate workaround to allow `File`s to be written to immutably.

It works in the first case because `&f` creates a temporary, which can be used mutably. The reason why `write!(f, ...` (with `f` being `&File`) doesn't work is because `f` is a variable that `write_fmt` wants to modify, so it needs to be `mut`.

```
fn write_hi(mut f: &File) {
         // ^^^
    write!(f, "hi").unwrap();
}
```

See also:

- [Why is it possible to implement Read on an immutable reference to File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31503488/why-is-it-possible-to-implement-read-on-an-immutable-reference-to-file)

Comment: I don't understand this part: 'It works in the first case because &f creates a temporary, which can be used mutably'. What do you mean with 'creates a temporary'?

Comment: The result of any expression that isn't assigned to a variable is called a temporary value because it only lives until the end of the statement.