# Why does serde_json::from_reader take ownership of the reader?

Tags: json, rust, serde

My code:

```
fn request_add<T>(request: &mut Request, collection_name: &'static str) -> Fallible<Fallible<String>>
where
    T: serde::Serialize + serde::de::DeserializeOwned,
{
    let add_dao = dao::MongoDao::new(collection_name);
    let obj = serde_json::from_reader::<Body, T>(request.body)?; //cannot move out of borrowed content
    Ok(add_dao.add(&obj))
}
```

I have a `cannot move out of borrowed content` error, because `request` is a reference, but why does `serde_json::from_reader` not use a mut reference? Why does it need ownership? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because it's an [API guideline](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/api-guidelines/interoperability.html#generic-readerwriter-functions-take-r-read-and-w-write-by-value-c-rw-value):

> #### Generic reader/writer functions take `R: Read` and `W: Write` by value (C-RW-VALUE)
>
> The standard library contains these two impls:
>
> ```
> impl<'a, R: Read + ?Sized> Read for &'a mut R { /* ... */ }
>
> impl<'a, W: Write + ?Sized> Write for &'a mut W { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> That means any function that accepts `R: Read` or `W: Write` generic
>   parameters by value can be called with a `mut` reference if necessary.

You either call [`Read::by_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.by_ref) or just take a reference yourself:

```
serde_json::from_reader(&mut request.body)
```

```
serde_json::from_reader(request.body.by_ref())
```

See also:

- [Read an arbitrary number of bytes from type implementing Read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31501921/155423)
- [How to use a file with a BufReader and still be able to write to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33831265/155423)
- [Why does Iterator::take_while take ownership of the iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31374051/155423)