# Why does serde_json::to_writer not require its argument to be `mut`?

Tags: rust

So I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51809603/why-does-serde-jsonfrom-reader-take-ownership-of-the-reader) question which explains how `serde_json` can both take Readers/Writers by reference or alternatively take ownership of them. Fair enough.

But I don't get how this works for `Write` - all of `Write` methods require a `&mut self`, so I'd think that if I pass a method that only knows its argument is a reference to something that is `Write` it can't do anything with it. But this example compiles and works just fine, even though I'm passing a non-mut ref to a method that, one way or another, ends up writing to the referenced file:

```
extern crate serde_json;

use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::error::Error;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let file = OpenOptions::new()
        .create(true)
        .write(true)
        .truncate(true)
        .open("/tmp/serde.json")?;
    // why does this work?
    serde_json::to_writer(&file, &10)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

I'm passing a `&File` - as expected, if I were to directly call any of `Write`'s methods on a `File` it doesn't work:

```
use std::io::{self, Write};
use std::fs::OpenOptions;

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let file = OpenOptions::new()
        .create(true)
        .write(true)
        .truncate(true)
        .open("/tmp/wtf")?;
    let file_ref = &file;
    // this complains about not having a mutable ref as expected
    file_ref.write(&[1,2,3])?;
    Ok(())
}
```

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `file_ref` as mutable, as it is not declared as mutable
  --> test.rs:12:5
   |
10 |     let file_ref = &file;
   |         -------- help: consider changing this to be mutable: `mut file_ref`
11 |     // this complains about not having a mutable ref as expected
12 |     file_ref.write(&[1,2,3])?;
   |     ^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

So what gives? Is `serde_json` breaking the type system somehow, or is this an intentional feature of the type system? If it's the latter, how does it work and why does it work like that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`serde_json::to_writer`'s first parameter accepts any type that implements `Write`. [One such value is `&File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/trait.Write.html#impl-Write-10).

This may be surprising, but the docs for `File` explicitly state that the mutability of the *reference* to a file has no bearing on whether the file will change or not:

> Note that, although read and write methods require a `&mut File`, because of the interfaces for `Read` and `Write`, the holder of a `&File` can still modify the file, either through methods that take `&File` or by retrieving the underlying OS object and modifying the file that way. Additionally, many operating systems allow concurrent modification of files by different processes. Avoid assuming that holding a `&File` means that the file will not change.

This might have you asking - wait, I thought the methods on `Write` took `&mut self`? And they do! But in this case, `Write` is implemented for `&File`, so the type passed to `Write` is, somewhat confusingly, `&mut &File` (a mutable reference to an immutable reference).

This explains why your second example doesn't compile - you need to be able to take a mutable reference to `&file`, and you can't do that without the binding being mutable. This is an important thing to realize - the mutablilty of a binding and the mutability of the bound value are not necessarily the same.

This is hinted at in the error message when you run your code:

```rust
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `file_ref` as mutable, as it is not declared as mutable
  --> src/lib.rs:11:5
   |
10 |     let file_ref = &file;
   |         -------- help: consider changing this to be mutable: `mut file_ref`
11 |     file_ref.write(&[1,2,3])?;
   |     ^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable

error: aborting due to previous error
```

If you change `let file_ref = &file;` to `let mut file_ref = &file;`, your code compiles.

Comment: Very nice explanation! It is worth noting that when writing a generic function that takes a `Read` or `Write` you should always take it by value, not by reference, just like `serde` does.

Comment: Yep - the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51809603/why-does-serde-jsonfrom-reader-take-ownership-of-the-reader) that the asker linked has that as an answer as well :)