# How to call serde_json::to_writer twice with the same mutable borrow?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a function that calls [`serde_json::to_writer`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/ser/fn.to_writer.html) twice to write two things, but I can't figure out how.

Here's one attempt ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ba84dbb8bf57466b92ec432894e86e44)):

```rust
extern crate serde_json;

fn main() {
    let mut out = std::fs::File::create("out.txt").unwrap();
    write_stuff(&mut out);
}

fn write_stuff<W: ?Sized>(out: &mut W) -> Result<(), std::io::Error>
where
    W: std::io::Write,
{
    serde_json::to_writer(out, &1).unwrap();  // `out`: value moved here
    serde_json::to_writer(out, &2).unwrap();  // `out`: value used here after move
    Ok(())
}
```

**Edit**: Figured out a way to get things to compile, but is there an easier way ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=93cd2ecee8b003f6f8c11eb9a0d943ab)):

```rust
extern crate serde_json;

fn main() {
    let mut out = std::fs::File::create("out.txt").unwrap();
    write_stuff(&mut out);
}

fn write_stuff<W: ?Sized>(out: &mut W)
where
    W: std::io::Write,
{
    write_wrapper(out);
    write_wrapper(out);
}

fn write_wrapper<W: ?Sized>(out: &mut W)
where
    W: std::io::Write,
{
    serde_json::to_writer(out, &1).unwrap();  
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does serde\_json::from\_reader take ownership of the reader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51809603/why-does-serde-jsonfrom-reader-take-ownership-of-the-reader) So, you just need to call serde_json::to_writer(&mut out, &1).

Comment: I don't think this is an exact duplicate. In the other question, the problem is that the function takes ownership, and we need to create a borrow. Here, `out` already _is_ a mutable borrow, but the compiler does not create an implicit reborrow, as it usually does when passing on mutable references to function calls, so we need to explicitly reborrow `out`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is somewhat subtle. When passing a shared reference as parameter to a function, Rust will simply copy the reference. The type `&T` is `Copy` for all `T`, since we are allowed to have any number of shared references at the same time.

Mutable references, on the other hand, are not `Copy`, since there can be only one of them at any given time. According to the usual Rust semantics for non-`Copy` types, this means that mutable references should be moved when passed as a parameter. So why does this code work?

```
fn foo(_: &mut i32) {}

fn main() {
    let mut i = 42;
    let r = &mut i;
    foo(r);
    foo(r);
}
```

The reason is that the compiler creates an *implicit reborrow* whenever it assigns to a variable that is explicitly declared as a mutable reference, so the function calls are translated to `foo(&mut *r)`. This creates a new borrow that only lasts for the duration of the function call, and the original reference `r` becomes available again once the lifetime of the reborrow ends.

However, implicit reborrows are only generated for variables that are explicitly declared with a mutable reference type. If we change the definition of `foo()` above to

```
fn foo<T>(_: T) {}
```

the code will stop compiling. Now the parameter of `foo()` is not declared as a mutable reference anymore, so the compiler will not introduce an implicit reborrow, and will move ownership of `r` into the function in the first call instead, resulting in an error in the second function call.

The same thing happens in your code. The function `to_writer()` is declared as

```
pub fn to_writer<W, T: ?Sized>(writer: W, value: &T) -> Result<()>
where
    W: io::Write,
    T: Serialize,
```

Since the argument `writer` is not declared as a mutable reference, you need to create an explicit reborrow to avoid a move:

```
serde_json::to_writer(&mut *out, &1)?;
```

The alternative solution you gave in your question works as well – the `write_wrapper()` function receives an explicitly declared mutable reference as argument, so calls to this function trigger implicit reborrows.