# Mutable reference to a vector was moved due to this implicit call to `.into_iter()`, but calling `.into_iter()` explicitly works

Tags: rust

This will fail:

```
fn ppv(arr: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    if arr.len() <= 0 {
       return;
    }
    let mut pp: i32 = 0;
    for &mut val in arr {
        if val == pp {
            pp = val;
        }
    }
    println!("arr is {:?}", &arr);
}
```

But this will pass:

```
fn ppv(arr: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    if arr.len() <= 0{
       return;
    }
    let mut pp: i32 = 0;
    for &mut val in arr.into_iter() {
        if val == pp {
            pp = val;
        }
    }
    println!("arr is {:?}", &arr);
}
```

when I compile the first one, it failed:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `arr`
   --> src/main.rs:12:29
    |
2   | fn ppv(arr: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    |        --- move occurs because `arr` has type `&mut Vec<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
7   |     for &mut val in arr {
    |                     --- `arr` moved due to this implicit call to `.into_iter()`
...
12  |     println!("arr is {:?}", &arr);
    |                             ^^^^ value borrowed here after move
    |
```

Why is that? Is it interpreting it differently?
First case will implicit call `into_iter()`, it failed, when I call `into_iter()`, it passed. What happened?

Comment: Related: [Do mutable references have move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62960584/do-mutable-references-have-move-semantics)

Comment: This is caused by the difference between `IntoIterator::into_iter(arr)` and `arr.into_iter()`. The `for` loop will implicitly invoke the former, which does not trigger a reborrow. The latter uses Rust's method resolution, which first determines the actual type of the receiver, and it does trigger an implicit reborrow. This difference is rather random, and you just need to live with it. The implicit reborrow rarely causes any problem, and if it doesn't happen, you can always perform an explicit one, so it's not much of a problem in practice.

Comment: @user4815162342 [My second sentence is correct.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b76f473fa7ed9cd53eacbf128c624484)

Comment: @SvenMarnach I stand corrected - and serves me right for not checking!

Comment: @user4815162342 Cases are different, since `IntoIterator` is [implemented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-IntoIterator) on `&'a mut Vec<T>`, when you call `into_iter(self)`, in here self will be `&'a mut Vec<T>`

Comment: The question is always: Is the type of the argument already known to be a mutable reference to the compiler, or is this only determined after performing type inference on the argument? In the case of `Vec::push()`, the type of the first argument is already known to be a mutable reference `&mut Vec<T>`, and type inference only infers the item type of the vector. In the case of `IntoIterator::into_iter()`, the type of the first argument is only known to be a mutable reference after type inference. As I said before, this behaviour isn't particularly intuitive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the difference is in [reborrow](https://github.com/rust-lang/reference/issues/788), performed in the latter case, but not the former.

Mutable references are normally not `Copy`. This is by design, as copying a mutable reference would allow mutable aliasing. But then, the question is how does this work:

```
fn foo(v: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    v.push(1);  // equivalent to Vec::push(v, 1)
    v.push(2);  // equivalent to Vec::push(v, 2)
}
```

If the first call to `push()` receives `v`, which is not `Copy`, then the second call to `push()` should fail to compile with "use of moved value". And yet [it compiles](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3321be22fda998ac7f10e8e67b458dab), as does the [desugared version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=88b459d8149c8c310299927022ae21e9) that invokes `Vec::push()` explicitly.

The reason it compiles is that the compiler automatically performs a trick referred to as "reborrowing", where it replaces the reference `v` with the equivalent reference `&mut *v`. This transformation is done both on the receiver (`self`) and the function arguments:

```
// v is &mut Vec<i32>
v.push(1);        // treated as (&mut *v).push(1)
Vec::push(v, 2);  // treated as Vec::push(&mut *v, 2)
```

The reborrowed form compiles because it creates a fresh temporary mut reference projected from an existing mut reference. This is the same mechanism that allows you to create `&mut r.some_field` given an `r: &mut SomeStruct`. That doesn't violate mutable aliasing prohibition as long as the temporary reference lives shorter than the original, and you don't attempt to use the original reference while the temporary one is live.

One typically becomes aware of reborrowing in the exceptional cases when it *fails*. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58336587/1600898) describes such case with serde, where reborrowing failed due to use of generics.

To get back to the original example, your `for` loop is another example of reborrow failing to happen. Given a mutable reference `arr`, the difference between `for &mut val in arr` and `for &mut val in arr.into_iter()` is that the explicit call to `into_iter()` is treated as `(&mut *arr).into_iter()` and thereby allows continued use of `arr` after the loop. The naked `for` doesn't do so, and the `arr` object is lost.

Comment: relevant blog post: https://bluss.github.io/rust/fun/2015/10/11/stuff-the-identity-function-does/

Comment: It would be nice if you can explain why the implicit call to `into_iter()` does not reborrow the reference as "normal" calls do.

Comment: Note that it also works if you do an explicit reborrow: `for &mut val in &mut*arr` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c451419c79088846c68b0f573ff2df35)).

Comment: Nice! But how do I konw when or which condition reborrowing will hapen?

Comment: @ban There's not much documentation on reborrowing. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/reference/issues/788) about improving the documentation (mainly about the implicit/automatic reborrowing that the compiler is able to do in some cases). Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66288291/what-is-a-reborrow-and-how-does-it-influence-the-code-the-compiler-generates) has some explanations about explicit reborrows.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev I don't know why the reborrow doesn't occur in case of `for`. The way I see it, reobrrow is a best-effort kind of thing, and the effort is presumably missing for `for`.

Comment: @ban The question I linked under your question has information about implicit reborrows.